# tf.data.dataset: How do I assign shape to a dataset (with shape undefined) that is guaranteed to output certain shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a tf2 Dataset API `dataset`, which undergoes multiple `map` operations followed by `tf.image.resize` that constantly outputs shape `(300, 300)` i.e. each record is guaranteed to have this shape after all map operations. However, this is not inherently inferred, and hence the Tensor Spec shows `<undefined>, <undefined>` shape. Undefined shaped datasets throw an error if they are passed to a model with pre-defined input shape.

Some searching helped me find this function [tf.contrib.data.assert_element_shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/assert_element_shape) and [Issue #16052](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16052):

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.assert_element_shape(custom_shape))
```

But this function has been removed in tf2, and the docs does NOT recommend using something else in place of assert_element_shape. **What is it's equivalent? Or how do I assign shape to a dataset that is guaranteed to output certain shape?**

Comment: If you know that your output after `tf.image.resize` is `(300, 300)` can't you just set hard coded shape with `set_shape()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, adding `set_shape` within the map function where I added `tf.image.resize` does NOT work.

```py
# does not work
def my_map_function(image, label):
    # some image operations here
    image = tf.image.resize(image, size=[300, 300])
    image.set_shape((300, 300, 3))
    return image, label
```

But when I made a separate map function, it works:

```py
# works
def set_shapes(image, label):
    image.set_shape((300, 300, 3))
    label.set_shape([])
    return image, label
```

Perhaps I'll stick to this until a direct `assert_element_shape` or `set_element_shape` gets added as separate functions

Comment: I think you meant to write 'def' instead of 'function' for the top function definition

Comment: Sorry that's something I mistyped, I've updated it now

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet of code in the accepted answer will actually work if you put 'set_shape' line before the 'resize' line.

Comment: Please add a code snippet where you show what you mean.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).